# Alter table with new default failing

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to update a table and change the default value on two columns to 0 instead of NULL. The problem is the alter command fails because many of the rows have a null value for those columns. Is there a way I could run the alter command and if it comes across a row with a NULL value to set it to 0 in one command? I could use a query to update the rows with NULL values but I want to be able to run one alter command using the Percona Toolkit which will allow for online alter table commands.

Comment: please post some code... and if possible, also the table structure

Comment: Why does the table structure matter? I'm just asking if it is possible to change NULL values to the new default in an alter command. I suspect it's not possible and I will have to run the update to change all NULL values to 0 in the table before I do the alter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your table first and change `null` values to `0`

```
update your_table 
set col = 0 where col is null;

alter table your_table 
change col 
       col int not null default 0;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e73cb/1)

Comment: Sorry should have made it clearer I guess. I know I can update the table and set null values to 0. I have the commands for that and the alter command. What I want is to be able to do them both in the same command. My table has 100,000,000 rows so I want to be able to run this in one command if possible.

Comment: AFAIK you **need** 2 commands for this in MySQL. Otherwise you get a *data truncation* error

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
UPDATE mysql.table_name
SET column_name = IFNULL(column_name,'0')
```